# How to add a label over slider selector

Tags: plotly-dash

How can I get a little label telling me what number I have selected on a slider in Dash for python? I am using dash_core_components.Slider().

I essentially want to have something with the little blue "500" label shown on the first slider [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sliders.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example given [here](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/rangeslider) shows how to update a label according to the value of the slider. I have modified it a bit in the code below to use a Slider as you wanted (instead of RangeSlider), and to update the label while dragging (instead of on mouse-up):

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(id='slider-wrapper', children=[
    dcc.Slider(
        id='my-slider',
        min=0,
        max=20,
        step=0.5,
        value=5,
        updatemode='drag',
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container-range-slider'),
    # Need onload script: $('#slider-wrapper .rc-slider-handle').appendChild($('#output-container-range-slider'));
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container-range-slider', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-slider', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return str(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Unfortunately, this does not place the label as a small flag above the slider as you wanted. There is no simple solution for that, but you could use JavaScript to make the label div follow the slider handle, and execute it on page load.

You can [add your own CSS and JavaScript to dash apps](https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources), so add the following snippets:

CSS:

```
#slider-wrapper {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#output-container-range-slider {
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  top: -40px;
  background-color: #428BCA;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;  /* Hide flag until it is moved */
}
```

JS:

```
function appendToSlider() {
  var flag = document.getElementById('output-container-range-slider');
  document.querySelector('#slider-wrapper .rc-slider-handle').appendChild(flag);
  flag.style.display = 'block';  // Make visible after moving
}

setTimeout(appendToSlider, 2000);
```

Notice the workaround using `setTimeout` - ideally you want the `appendToSlider` function to get executed right after the slider is rendered, if there was such an event to attach it to. I could not find a way to that, but that is an issue for a separate thread.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that :( I guess for now I will just settle for a label that I update with the value of the slider. Thanks anyway though :)

Comment: @oskaboska, BTW, I managed to get the label to act like a flag above the slider, but this requires a JQuery code to be executed after the slider element is loaded. I could not find a way to do that in dash though...

Comment: Ooh, do you reckon you could share your code? I'm not great with JQuery so I'd appreciate the help

Comment: @oskaboska, please see the edited answer. Kindly accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 7):

Update on this issue: always-visible tooltips (i.e. value labels) are [now available](https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/pull/564) for `dcc.Slider()` and `dcc.RangeSlider()` as of Dash 1.0 with the argument `tooltip`:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
...
    dcc.Slider(..., tooltip = { 'always_visible': True })
```

You can install Dash >=1.0 with

```sh
pip install dash
```

The latest version of Dash is 1.9.1